# Get Eloquent (Laravel) to return object without relationship

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Please consider this method of in the User model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryUserModel;

class User extends SentryUserModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

//[...]

public function company()
{
    Log::info("SPOOFED", array($this->getSpoofedCompanyId()));
    // == 1


    if($this->getSpoofedCompanyId() > 0) {
        return Company::find($this->getSpoofedCompanyId());
    }
    else {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
LogicException
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

I guess I'm not allowed to return an object which has no relation? Is there any way to bypass this?

The reason is that I'm letting a superuser impersonate another user.

Comment: Could you try to replace `return $this->belongsTo('Company');` with something like `return Company::find($this->company_id);` ?!